How to Call a Dart Function from Native Linux Code in Flutter?
I’m working on a Flutter application for Linux and need to call a Dart function from my native C++ code. I’ve successfully implemented method channels for calling native C++ functions from Dart, but I’m having trouble with the reverse — calling Dart functions from C++.
Context:
I want to send data from the native C++ side to Dart and invoke a Dart function based on certain events or conditions in the native code.
I’ve explored using Flutter's platform channels, but all the examples and documentation I found seem to focus on invoking methods from Dart to native code rather than the other way around. Specifically, I tried setting up a MethodChannel but couldn’t figure out how to call Dart functions directly from the native side.
Goal:

Native Side: I need to trigger a Dart function from the native side of my application (C++ for Linux).

Dart Side: The Dart function should be callable from the native code and handle any incoming data or events.



https://api.flutter.dev/linux-embedder/classflutter_1_1_method_channel.html#aa69fcf28e0df0d4f532adff51b6c1682

Could you please show me a working example? As I mentioned, I tried setting up a MethodChannel but couldn’t figure out how to call Dart functions from C++ @pskink

just call the method I linked, on the dart side call setMethodCallHandler - this is exactly like calling a method from dart to native but  reversed

I could not find the method you mentioned. I found fl_method_channel_invoke_method instead, do they have the same functionality? @pskink

Start by creating a Flutter "plugin" project. This comes ready built with some sample code and an example app to exercise it with. (When you use the plugin for real, the example code isn't included of course.) Let's say you call your project "myplug". Look in the file ./linux/myplug_plugin.cpp This shows the template of Dart->Linux. So far so good. Now you can use any example from Android or iOS to illustrate invoking methods from native (using invokeMethod, of course, as noted by pskink above). If you get stuck, you'll have code to show in your question.

One word of caution. Be sure to only invoke methods on the main thread. Don't try doing that from threads you create yourself in C++.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
